# How can i create array of pictureBoxess?

Tags: c#, winforms

I did:

```
pbs = new PictureBox[8];
            pbs[0].Location = new Point(12, 27);
            for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
            {
                pbs[i].Size = new Size(100, 100);
                this.Controls.Add(pbs[i]);
            }
```

pbs is pictureBox[]

What i need is to somehow calculate the spaces between the pictureBoxes.
For example pictureBox2 should be at location: 12,160
The next one at 12,....
And 4 pictureBoxes at each side of the Form.
My form1 size is 800x600
So i want 4 pictureBoxes on the left side and 4 on the right size.

How can i calculate the locations ?

Comment: Using addition?  Just add the gap to the location of previous PictureBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to calculate the location that way, we should use some **layout control** to solve this. Just add 2 `Panels`, the first one is docked on the left side of your form, the second is docked on the right side of your form.

```
panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
panel1.Width = panel2.Width = 100;
```

Now, you just need to add 4 pictureboxes to `panel1` and 4 pictureboxes to `panel2`, also using `Dock` property like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++) {
   pbs[i].Size = new Size(100, 100);
   pbs.Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 60);
   pbs.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
   Panel p = i < 4 ? panel1 : panel2;
   p.Controls.Add(pbs[i]);
   pbs.BringToFront();
}
```

You can also use `FlowLayoutPanel` instead of `Panel`, it will dock controls automatically for you.

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
flowLayoutPanel2.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
flowLayoutPanel1.Width = flowLayoutPanel2.Width = 100;
flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = flowLayoutPanel2.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;

for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++) {
   pbs[i].Size = new Size(100, 100);
   pbs.Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 60);
   Control p = i < 4 ? flowLayoutPanel1 : flowLayoutPanel2;
   p.Controls.Add(pbs[i]);
}
```